# How to use "Scheduler.get().scheduleDeferred" the right way in GWT?

Tags: gwt, gwt-platform, gwtp

Here is my Pseudocode in my GWT app.

```
-Visible the loading Label
-Loading text from properties file (may take long)
-Invisible the loading Label & Visible the main HTMLPanel
```

So I want to use `Scheduler.get().scheduleDeferred` to achive that, here is the code:

```
loadingLabel.setVisible(true);
Scheduler.get().scheduleDeferred(new ScheduledCommand() { 
  @Override
  public void execute() {
   loadingText();
  }
}
loadingLabel.setVisible(false);
mainHTMLPanel.setVisible(true);
```

But it doesn't work correctly as it did not show the loadingLabel but show the mainHTMLPanel immediately & when i click a textbox inside the mainHTMLPanel since the Gui got frozen cos it is loading text. Then I have to wait for a while to be able to click the textbox inside mainHTMLPanel.

But if i put `loadingLabel.setVisible(false);` & `mainHTMLPanel.setVisible(true);` inside `execute()` Then it works.

But i am not sure that is the right way to do.

So, is the following code the right way to use `Scheduler.get().scheduleDeferred`?

```
    loadingLabel.setVisible(true);
    Scheduler.get().scheduleDeferred(new ScheduledCommand() { 
      @Override
      public void execute() {
       loadingText();
       loadingLabel.setVisible(false);
       mainHTMLPanel.setVisible(true);
      }
    }
```

Comment: Did you checkout http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsDelayed.html?

Comment: How loadingText is implemented? It is a call to an async method?

Comment: no it load Text from Properties file, like it load all cities in the world from properties file

Answer (score 0):

Use a scheduler with "fixed delay" that will check each 100 milliseconds that the text content is loaded. Once the text is loaded hide your "loadingLabel" and display the "mainHTMLPanel".

```
mainHTMLPanel.setVisible(false);
loadingLabel.setVisible(true);

Scheduler.get().scheduleFixedDelay(new Scheduler.RepeatingCommand() {
   @Override
   public boolean execute() {
       if (isTextLoaded())  {
            loadingLabel.setVisible(false);
            mainHTMLPanel.setVisible(true);
            return false;
       }
       else {return true;}
    }
}, 100);

private boolean isTextLoaded() {
    // Dummy check
    MyWidgetContainingText.getContent().isNotEmpty();
}
```

Comment: then i need to check when all data got loaded, is there other way

Comment: Consider the following: If you don't check how will you know if the text is loaded ? And if you don't know if it is loaded how can you decide to display the HTMLPanel or not ? If your purpose is to display an element only after its content is ready, I think my answer will work for you. Could you give more details about what it is you don't like about it ?

Comment: the thing is that I don't want to make a saperated method isTextLoaded(). I tried to use ur method but doing without isTextLoaded methos & somehow it doesn't work, it not show the loading label

Comment: 1° You don't have to write a separate method. If you want to put everything at the same place just put the check in the if condition. 2° The loading label is displayed OUTSIDE the scheduler call and is hidden INSIDE the scheduler call. If the loading label doesn't show up either you didn't displayed it before the call, either the text loads so quickly that you can't even see it before it is hidden. If you don't write a correct if condition it will execute loadingLabel.setVisible(false);, of course.

Comment: I did use ur technique, but it still didn't show the loadingLabel. I found a way, that is i put the loadingText() inside Timer & let it run in 2 seconds, then this time the loadingLabel got showing up. Is it a right way to do?

Comment: Sure you can if it's the only way for you to make this work. Be aware this is not very clean since you might have the user wait 2000 milliseconds when 200 is enough. I think the reason the loadingLabel doesn't show up using my method is because the if test is incorrect. Could you post some code to explain how you figure out that the text is loaded ?

Comment: very simple loop. it's MultiWordSuggestOracle. This is the loop "for (int i=0; i<countries.length; i++) { mySuggestOracles.add(countries[i]); }"

Comment: ok, how do you inform the scheduler that the text is loaded once you are at the end of the loop ?

Comment: this is my code: loadingLabel.setVisible(true);  Timer t = new Timer() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        loadingText(); mainHTMLPanel.setVisible(true);
      }
    }; t.schedule(200); let the code inside Timer run after 200 miliseconds

Comment: I tought loadingText() was the method taking a lot of time to execute, but you call it inside the timer. I'm lost & I'm done. Good luck with your problem !

Comment: Thax u very much anyway, i am happy with Timer solution