# Google Map GWT does not fit container size

Tags: java, google-maps, gwt, google-maps-api-3

I'm having troubles making a second call to load a Google Map in a GWT app. The problem itself is that once the map is called, it won't fit the container size. This is a usual problem, as depicted in many previous SO questions:

1. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11530334/second-call-of-google-maps-does-not-show-the-map-in-correct-size)
2. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11530334/second-call-of-google-maps-does-not-show-the-map-in-correct-size)
3. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5454535/fire-resizeevent-in-gwt-google-web-toolkit?lq=1)
4. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11543276/trigger-resize-event-to-google-maps-from-gwt-2-5-using-gwt-maps-3-8-0?lq=1)

Let me state that I've tried all of the above and sadly nothing seems to work. I must also say I'm using the unofficial version of GWT Maps API v3, which can be found [here](https://github.com/branflake2267/GWT-Maps-V3-Api). Thus, this is the problem:

[image]

Now, weird enough, if I change the browser size, map displays correctly:

[image]

Thus, it looks like I need to "dispatch" the onResize event somehow...but I tried with all of the above methods and nothing seemed to work. Just for clarification this, is the part where I construct the map and add it to the container:

```
private void buildMapMarinesPark() {
    //Visualizar datos...
    LatLng center = LatLng.newInstance(52.62715,1.7734);
        MapOptions opts = MapOptions.newInstance();
        opts.setZoom(9);
        opts.setCenter(center);
        opts.setMapTypeId(MapTypeId.HYBRID);
        MapTypeControlOptions controlOptions = MapTypeControlOptions.newInstance();
        controlOptions.setMapTypeIds(MapTypeId.values()); // use all of them
        controlOptions.setPosition(ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT);
        opts.setMapTypeControlOptions(controlOptions);
        mapMarinePark = new MapWidget(opts);
        mapMarinePark.setSize("100%", "100%");
        // Add some controls for the zoom level
        List<EuropeanMarineParkDataEntity> parksPerAnio = null;
        listPolygon = new ArrayList<Polygon>();
        Polygon poly = null;
        for(int i=2003;i<=ANIO_MAP_PARK;i++){   
            parksPerAnio = this.hashAnioParks.get(""+i);
            if(parksPerAnio != null){
            for(EuropeanMarineParkDataEntity emp : parksPerAnio){
                poly = this.createPolygon(emp);
                poly.setMap(mapMarinePark);
                listPolygon.add(poly);
                }
            }
        }       
        ((Element)DOM.getElementById("currentYear")).setPropertyObject("innerHTML", ""+(ANIO_MAP_PARK));

        // Add the map to the HTML host page
        final DockLayoutPanel dock = new DockLayoutPanel(Unit.PX);
        dock.addNorth(mapMarinePark, 500);

        RootPanel.get("mapContainerProfile2").add(dock); 
        RootPanel.get("timeline").setVisible(true); 
        RootPanel.get("mapPanel2").setVisible(true); 
        RootPanel.get("gadget_marinepark").setVisible(true); 
        mapMarinePark.triggerResize(); --> Does not work!           
        onLoadedMapMarinePark();

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you try to draw the map when the DOM hasn't been fully constructed and the wrong dimensions are retrieved.
Try to draw/create the map in a callback of a 
`Scheduler.get().scheduleDeferred()` call.

**Update**:
Also you are mixing a `DockLayoutPanel` with a `RootPanel`.
That will cause issues. Use a `RootLayoutPanel` instead.

Construct the DOM normally and at the point where you normally add your map to the `DockLayoutPanel` call `scheduleDeferred()` and add the map to the panel in the callback

Comment: Hello Umit! Any guide on how to do that? This question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19647905/how-to-use-scheduler-get-scheduledeferred-the-right-way-in-gwt is somehow related, but how can I check the DOM is fully built? Thanks!

Comment: Okie dokie, I'll try and let you know. Thanks you :)

Comment: I'm afraid this solution did not work...I add the map to the RootPanel in the execute()  method but still, map is not behaving correctly. Weird thing is that if the browser resize event is fired (manually by me), it automatically redraws correctly...I'm puzzled

Comment: No you should **not** use a `RootPanel`. Use a `RootLayoutPabel`. Add the `DockLayoutPanel` to the `RootLayoutPanel` and then add the `Map` in the callback to the north region of your `DockLayoutPanel`

Comment: What is the reason to use the RootLayoutPanel insted of the RootPanel? Would be nice to know...

Comment: You should `RootLayoutPanel` if you want to use any other `LayoutPanel`s (i.e. `DockLayoutPanel`). If you don't then the automatic `onResize()` won't work and you run into these issues. See [here](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideUiPanels.html#LayoutPanels) for more infos

Comment: Thanks for the tip, unfortunately, I changed my RootPanel to RootLayoutPanel instead but the issue is still there..

Comment: A user posted an answer that for some reason is not showing up now...(??? SO bug???) but that does work, since it fires the triggerResize event, after some time passes. Timer timer = new Timer(){

               @Override
               public void run(){
                       LatLng center = LatLng.newInstance(43.2566901,-2.4240616);
                   buoyMmap.triggerResize();
                   buoyMmap.setCenter(center);
               }

           };  This works, altough I feel is some sort of a hack...

Comment: Put a breakpoint in the `triggerResize` function and check if the `width` and `height` are correctly retrived. You can call `triggerResize` in the `Scheduler.get().scheduleDeferred()` callback instead of the `Timer`

Comment: What should be best? GWT official doc suggests both Time and Scheduler for this kind of tasks...anyway I'll try it out..

Comment: `Timer` is usually used for periodically running logic. `scheduleDeferred` is for running things after the event loop. 
http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsDelayed.html