# Google Map does not fit container

Tags: google-maps, gwt

I am experiencing the same problem as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20294058/google-map-gwt-does-not-fit-container-size).  As the suggestion in the referenced issue did not solve my problem, I'm hoping someone has additional insight that might help me out.

I'm using gwt 2.5.1 and gwt-maps 3.8.0.  As shown in the images in the reference, my map is partially displayed in the upper left corner and only fills the panel when I manually re-size the browser.  The problem is present in both FF and IE9.

[Here](http://s23.postimg.org/v4pudng5n/mapscr.png) is a partial screen shot.  The map controls are placed in about the correct locations.  Its just the map tiles that are not displayed.

I've tried using Scheduler.scheduleDeferred to defer creation of the map without success.  I also used scheduleDeferred to resize the map as shown below without success

```
private final native void resizeMap(GoogleMap map) /*-{
$wnd.google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
map.setZoom( map.getZoom() ); 
}-*/;
```

My html body contains a div (id "map-container") which I pass to GoogleMap.create().

Element mapDiv= DOM.getElementById("map-container");
VerticalPanel mapPanel.add(RootPanel.get("map-container"));
...
GoogleMap.create(mapDiv, mapOptions);

The hierarchy looks like:

DockLayoutPanel (added to the RootLayoutPanel)

```
  DockLayoutPanel
        SimplePanel
            Caption Panel
                DockLayoutPanel
                    DeckPanel
                        VerticalPanel (mapPanel)
                            mapDiv
                                GoogleMap
```

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Maybe you can replace DeckPanel with DeckLayoutPanel. Other intermediate panels get sized correctly?